# Dual Graphic Card Setup (Integrated + Discrete) on Desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

My current setup is as follows:

- AMD HD Radeon 4250 integrated GPU
- Nvidia GTX 460 1 GB GPU
- Three monitors, two running via the GTX 460 and the other running via
  the onboard.

This setup works without any issues on Windows 10. I am able to output to two of the monitors via my GTX 460 and the third via the integrated card.

After trying this setup with Ubuntu 14.04 however, it did not work. Upon first installing Ubuntu I was able to get a video signal on all three monitors, however it had defaulted to using the Nouveau Nvidia driver (which is really sluggish and slow). So I installed the Nvidia proprietary driver (352 I believe) and upon restarting Ubuntu I was greeted with the following message:

[image]

Is what I'm trying to do possible on Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Nvidia uses optimus in Windows to perform discrete and integrated GPU switching. There is some effort to bring this in to Linux as well, such as project bumblebee. However, it seems like it is outdated. I personally just install the proprietary Nvidia driver and forget this switching as it seems not fully supported, especially for more recent GPU.

Check this out for more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Sorry, I can't help much beyond this answer, I also just started with Linux.

Comment: I'm not switching between graphics cards. I'm running both at the same time on a DESKTOP machine. From what I understand, Optimus is for laptops with discrete and integrated cards.